# Firebase with Large Obj. on value change Is it transfer (internet bandwidth) only delta change?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I have  a  node  contain array of 1000 nodes. [ex 60KB]

```
 rootRef.on('value', function (snapshot){  

     //callback every changes props ,  full list obj

 });
```

My question is
if some node in list change value,
 the client download data on **changes(DELTA) [1KB]** or full download **full node [60KB]?**

Comment: it will only download the delta although you will get the full list object. I rmb seeing the explanation in one of the firebase youtube videos.

Comment: Could you update the question with more context of the problem? I can't seem to find 100% proof that you don't get the changes[delta] by default. It may be as simple as coming at the problem from a different angle to make it work how you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say without more details, but generally speaking, the answer is just the change. Firebase caches the data (in memory) for as long as there is an active listener for that data.

Here is a similar question related to this topic:
[Does Firebase cache the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423277/does-firebase-cache-the-data)