# How to save firestore requests by using Http cache-control?

Tags: firebase, caching, http-caching, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say i have a web/mobile app running firebase firestore database.

My app is set to serve mostly **dynamic content** fully stored in firestore.

So we are talking about caching dynamic content

If a user load Page A, it's will make 1 request to firestore (for example). If this user go to Page B and then go back to Page A 5 minutes later, i don't want the app to make another request if the content has not changed.

I heard about `http cache-control` headers but my concern is. If the cache control go check firestore to learn if the content is still the same, will this operation be counted as a request by firestore ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firestore does not make requests in a way that HTTP Cache-Control headers would apply.

However, the [protocol](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/3273178ea4684acc4f512f7bef7349dd72db88f6/google/firestore/v1beta1/firestore.proto#L606) includes a notion of a resume token which allows entire queries to be resumed at a later time, possibly avoiding the retransmission of any unchanged documents that match the query.

If you [enable persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore#enablePersistence) in your web app, Firestore will cache the documents and resume tokens in a local IndexedDB for you. If you come back to a page later, it will use the resume token transparently and avoid retransmission.

Note a [pricing caveat](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing#operations):

> If the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as if you had issued a brand-new query.

So, to specifically address your question. If:

- you have persistence enabled,
- the underlying data hasn't changed,
- a user loads page A, and
- loads page A again 5 minutes later

Then Firestore will request the data for the page but the server will essentially respond that nothing has changed: no documents will be transferred and there will be no charge to confirm that.

Comment: Thank you. That's what i wanted to know.

Comment: Gil do we have to register no-op listeners for onSnapshot to cache data in memory like with Firebase RTDB? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423277/does-firebase-cache-the-data#answer-38423694

Comment: ^Just to confirm I tested adding a persistent listener, and it dropped response times from ~300ms to ~5ms. Wondering if `enablePersistence()` should handle this for us...?

Comment: Adding a listener indicates interest in a value, so yes if you absolutely want to pin something in RAM but don't care to do anything with it you can create a no-op listener to accomplish that. With persistence enabled you should be able to create listeners on demand and get responses from the local cache even without such things. Ask a separate, specific question and I'll go into more detail.

Comment: This comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46649022/firestore-serve-cached-datas-first#comment80251067_46649022 clarified persistence behavior for me. I was wondering why I wasn't seeing cache-first data, but I was using `get()` instead of `onSnapshot()`. It's not that I didn't want to do anything w/ data just wanted subsequent requests to be fast.