# Firestore: Serve cached datas first

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore can handle offline persistence but it doesn't seem to load cached datas first. Is that possible ?
The app perf would seem much better if the local datas were loaded first.

If not possible, is there an easy way to get the local datas manually so I can do an Observable merge and load cached datas first.

Thanks a lot

EDIT:

I'm using angularfire2 with Ionic 3.

I'm expecting an offline first behavior from Firestore.
Since valueChanges() returns an Observable, I think it should first emit the local value then when the remote datas have arrived emit the remote value.

For instance, if I do this:

```
return this.db.collection<HeroServerData>('game/heroes')
  .valueChanges()
  .map(heroes => heroes.map(hero => new Hero(hero)));
```

I can see that the data are cached locally but I still have to wait for the server response or a timeout (if offline) to get the datas

Comment: Can you add more details about what exactly you're doing (a code snippet) and what you're expecting? If you're attaching a snapshot listener and you have cached data available, I believe you should get an event immediately without waiting for the backend.  If you are using get() or you don't have any cached data, it will indeed wait for data from the backend.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What do you mean by "attaching a snapshot listener" ? I'm using valueChanges() on my collection. Is that ok ?

Comment: This may be an AngularFire issue. Let me see if I can get somebody to take a look.  If you use the raw Firestore Web SDK (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) and you attach a snapshot listener with db.collection('game/hereos').onSnapshot(snap => ... ) then it should give you an initial snapshot with the cached data.

Comment: Should I create an issue on Github ?

Comment: Sure!  https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues