# How to save Firestore database request on web to make less calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a product page with all my product and every time someone presses F5 it get executed. I want to save all de product but when a product is added it can get update once to reduce all the api calls.

- I tried to save it in Cookie, but that is nog a nice way.
- I tried to do it with Http cache-control but it dit not work ([How to save firestore requests by using Http cache-control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579285/how-to-save-firestore-requests-by-using-http-cache-control))
- I tried localstorage, but it did get not executed when a new product is added.

//JS file
My cookie try:
it works i only get a api call every 0.5 days but if a update happens in my product i only get is later

```
//if cookie === undifined
const firestore = firebase.firestore()
firestore.doc("products/phones").onSnapshot(function (doc) {
    if (doc && doc.exists) {
        const products = doc.data().produc
        //Save doc.data().produc in cookie 0.5 day expirery
    }
})
```

I want to save my Firestore request client side and only make a Firestore request when needed to update the product list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second approach has no chance of working. The `firebase.json` file is using by Firebase Hosting and completely unrelated to Cloud Firestore.

Your first approach could work, although you didn't include the code that actually determines when you attach the `onSnapshot` listener. But as you discovered, attaching the listener at most twice a day means that you only get updates at most twice a day, and that you may be serving stale data in the meantime.

It sounds like you'll have to choose between serving fresh data, and reducing server calls. This is a fairly common trade-off.

There are a few other ways to reduce the number of document reads needed to server the latest data though:

1. Include a timestamp when the data was updated in each document, and then use a query to only request new data. You'll keep the timestamp of when you last requested/got data in local storage, and use that in the query each time.
2. Aggregate the data for recent updates into one or a few documents, so that you have to read fewer documents.