# Avoid fetching the same data from Firestore over and over again whenever the app starts

Tags: swift, sqlite, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, realm

I am sorry, if it is a stupid question. I started to work with a Firestore db in a SwiftUI iOS App. Since I will be charged for every read/write/delete I try to avoid to read-in a snapshot with tons of documents (e.g. messages in a messenger app) every time the user starts the app.

I wondering what is the normal way to handle that? Do I have to write/save the messages locally into a sqlite or realm to fetch them at the next time from the internal db (on the Firestore side I create a query to read/load only documents that are newer than the last locally saved message)? Or does the Firestore (Firebase) has a built-in solution e.g. the cache?

Comment: Firebase SDK, I'm pretty sure, caches results locally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've already answered your question. You can save documents (messages) locally so you don't have to fetch them from Firestore every time (and only fetch the new ones). Firebase can [cache data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities) locally, but only [temporarily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38423694/14647052). Saving the data using sqlite, realm, or even CoreData is a wise move.