# Do Firebase Realtime Database uses cache

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, caching

Right now i'm using Firebase Realtime Database, is there a way to see if i'm reading data from the Realtime Database or from cache ?(i want the same way like `.isFromCache()` from https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/SnapshotMetadata).

i read from other stackoverflow question [Does Firebase cache the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423277/does-firebase-cache-the-data), that when i use `once()`, it clears the cache. is there any way to track where i'm reading the data ?

Comment: Answer below. But it sounds a bit like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It may be best to also tell us the reason you want check where the result came from, so that we can potentially help coming up with a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in the Realtime Database API calls or results to see whether a resulting snapshot came from the cache or from the server.

The `isFromCache` method from the Firestore API is not available on Realtime Database. It also doesn't necessarily do what you expect it to do, but that seems besides the point here.